# How to write a two variable function with an IF statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am trying to write a two variable equation that evaluates a hypothetical speed and boolean operator that reduces the speed by 5 if true. Depending on the speed and boolean operator the equation should print 'No Ticket', 'Small Ticket' or 'Big Ticket'.

I first tried writing this as a lambda expression but found out that lambda expressions must be a single line. I then wrote this as a normal expression, with the single x variable and it worked perfectly. After I added the Y variable, the function stopped working. I don't know if I am defining x wrong, if I cannot do nested IFs like I am trying, or if this needs to be two functions. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
def caught_speeding(x,y):
    if y == 1:
        x = x - 5
    else:
        x = x

        if x <= 60:
                return print('No Ticket')
        elif x > 60 or x <=80:
                return print('Small Ticket')
        elif x >= 81:
                return print('Big Ticket')

caught_speeding(100,0)
```

I am not getting any error messages. If I set y = 1 it always returns 'Small Ticket', if I set y = 0 then it does not return anything. :/

Comment: You don't need the `else:` line and your middle `if` is wrong. It should be: `elif x > 60 and x <= 80:` Oh yes, and the `return`s do nothing for you. Just use `print()`, unless you did mean to return strings.

Comment: In python formatting and especially indenting is very important, so please make sure you insert the code verbatim and you do preserve formatting.

Comment: `return print("string")` will return `None`, so I'd probably just `print`

Comment: Hi quamrana, thanks for your edits! I changed my code per your notes and it is no longer printing results for me.

Comment: Hi Roman, you may have been referring to the first instance of this post. I edited it to include the entire function. What you see in grey is the exact formatting I have in Jupyter. :)

Comment: Hi C.Nivs, I tried all variants of print in my jupyter notebook. I.e print lou, print 'lou', print('lou') and only the third iteration prints Lou

Comment: Yes, `print('lou')` is the correct syntax for python 3.

Comment: Sorry, Lou, you must keep the question basically intact, otherwise future readers won't be able to see the difference between what you posted and what the comments and answers say.

Comment: Hi everyone, Im a NEWB here and didn't see the answers below the comment section -.- I'll go ahead and edit back the code to what it was originally! And thank you to everyone for the help, vurmux's walk through got my code functioning properly. I didn't know that putting return and print together isn't right in python. Learned a lot from this! :) Looking forward to being an active member here, you all rock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need the first else-statement. This:

```
if y == 1:
    x = x - 5
else:
    x = x
```

is equal to:

```
if y == 1:
    x = x - 5
```

---

2. Looks like you have incorrect indenting. Python is heavily rely on it so you should always check your code indentation. Instead of this:

```
def caught_speeding(x,y):
    if y == 1:
        x = x - 5

        if x <= 60:
                return print('No Ticket')
        elif x > 60 or x <=80:
                return print('Small Ticket')
        elif x >= 81:
                return print('Big Ticket')
```

you should have this:

```
def caught_speeding(x,y):
    if y == 1:
        x = x - 5

    if x <= 60:
        return print('No Ticket')
    elif x > 60 or x <=80:
        return print('Small Ticket')
    elif x >= 81:
        return print('Big Ticket')
```

---

3. Logic error. Here: `elif x > 60 or x <=80:` you check that x>60 OR x<=80. It will always be true. Replace `or` with `and` and this if-statement will have sense.

---

4. `return` statement is returning the value you write after this word. But `print(...)` returns `None` so the line `return print(...)` is useless because it will always return `None`s. Python functions don't need `return`s, you can use only `print`s. OR you can use only `return`s and then print the result of the function. It depends from your needs.

Here is the result code:

```
def caught_speeding(x,y):
    if y == 1:
        x = x - 5

    if x <= 60:
        print('No Ticket')
    elif x > 60 and x <=80:
        print('Small Ticket')
    elif x >= 81:
        print('Big Ticket')

caught_speeding(100,0)
```

> `Big Ticket`

Comment: You could also mention the difference between using *either* `print('... Ticket')`, *or* `return '... Ticket'`

Comment: And, now that I think about it, the last `elif` is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Your second if-statement is only executed on the else: clause, because of your indentation ( it needs to be the same level of indentation as the first if-statement in the function). Also, you shouldnt return and print on the same line. So in this case we are returning a String and then printing that returned String at the end, outside the function where we are calling it.

So here is a corrected version of your code:

```
def caught_speeding(x,y):
    if y == 1:
        x = x - 5
    else:
        x = x

    if x <= 60:
        return 'No Ticket'
    elif x > 60 or x <=80:
        return 'Small Ticket'
    elif x >= 81:
        return 'Big Ticket'

print (caught_speeding(100,0))
print (caught_speeding(100,1))
```

Comment: btw your: `else: x=x` is redundant.

Comment: Yes thats very true! :)

Answer (score 2):

Lou, I would recommend you writing your function like this:

```
def caught_speeding(x,y):
    if y == 1:
        x = x - 5

    if x <= 60:
        return 'No Ticket'
    elif x > 60 and x <= 80:
        return 'Small Ticket'

    return 'Big Ticket'
```

And call it like this:

```
#Either by assignment:
result = caught_speeding(100,0)

#Or print the result:
print(caught_speeding(100,0))
```